# The seminorms that give the strict topology on the space of bounded continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

If $X$ is a completely regular space, then the strict topology on the algebra of its bounded continuous functions is usually taken to be given by the seminorms $f \mapsto \| f \|_\varphi = \sup \varphi |f|$, where $\varphi$ ranges over the positive bounded functions that vanish at infinity.

To my surprise, I have found a related, equivalent description [(first page)](https://www.impan.pl/shop/publication/transaction/download/product/89387), that claims that $\varphi$ may range only over the positive bounded **upper semi-continuous** functions that vanish at infinity. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reduction to usc case is made by the *upper semicontinuous regularization* of $\varphi$, defined as 
$$
\varphi^* (x) = \inf_{V\ni x}  \sup_V \varphi
$$
where the infimum is taken over all neighborhoods $V$ of $x$. By construction, the set $\{x : \varphi^* (x) < t\}$ is open for every $t$, which means $\varphi^*$ is upper semicontinuous.

Note that $\varphi\le \varphi^*$ (also, $\varphi^*$ is the smallest usc majorant of $\varphi$).

For every bounded continuous $f$ we have $\sup \varphi |f|  = \sup \varphi ^*|f|$. Indeed, $\le$ is clear. To prove $\ge$, take $t$ such that $t < \sup \varphi^* |f|$. Then there exists a point $x$ where $\varphi^*(x) |f(x)| > t$. By definition of $\varphi^*$, for every neighborhood $V\ni x$ we have $|f(x)| \sup_V \varphi > t$. Taking a sufficiently small neighborhood $V$ and using the continuity of $f$ we arrive at $\sup_V (\varphi|f|) > t$.

---

Aside: In a number of places it is written that "$\varphi^* (x) = \limsup_{y\to x} \varphi(y)$" which I think is a byproduct of terminological confusion around $\limsup$. The way $\limsup$ is defined, it is possible that $\limsup_{y\to x} \varphi(y)$ can be less than $\varphi(x)$. It would be correct to write  $\varphi^* (x) = \max(\varphi(x), \limsup_{y\to x} \varphi(y))$.